# what is the use of classes_array in drupal7 template.php

Tags: php, drupal-7

in template.php many times they used classes_array..am not getting the meaning and why they using,..what is the purpose of classes_array and when we have to use that in drupal7 .tpl.php

```
    example code:
    if(in_array('administrator',array_values($variables['user']->roles)))
    {
     $variables['classes_array'][]="debug";
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$variables['classes_array']` is used in preprocess functions. It adds classes to be used in rendering the element to be processed. In your example, a class named "debug" will be added to the html container of the rendered element: if the actual code is

```
function <YOUR THEME>_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  if (in_array('administrator',array_values($variables['user']->roles))) {
    $variables['classes_array'][]="debug";
  }
}
```

your theme will output a body tag like

```
<body class='debug [...OTHER CLASSES...]'>
```

for users with administrator role.

You can also add classes to nodes, or other kind of elements for which a preprocess hook is available. E.g. you could write a node preprocess function:

```
function <YOUR THEME>_preprocess_node($variables) {
  $classes_array[] = 'my-class';
}
```

if you wanted to add 'my-class' to every node of your site.

In general, you will not find `$classes_array` among the defined variables in tpl.php files. Your theme  will, most of the times, implode them in a `$classes` variable. It must be noted, however, that a kind of confusion arised over time, so different themes may use `$classes_array`, `$attribute_array`, `$classes`, `$attributes['class']` and so on for the same purpose, so you should check your theme's documentation to find out what suits your case.